# Error Installing mysql-python

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-2013, mysql-python

I am Using Python **3.4.3**. I am using Windows 7 32-bit version.

I installed MysqlDb successfully but I am having problems installing mysql-python using easy install. I am getting the below error.

**Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).**

I have installed **Visual Studio 2013**.

I have set the environment variable for **VS90COMNTOOLS**

I have installed **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable- 10.0.30319**

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem you're asking about here is just yet another duplicate of the `vcvarsall` problem, which you can search for.

But the far bigger problem is that, as the entry for [MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) says:

> MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently supported. Python-3.0 will be supported in a future release. PyPy is supported.

So, you cannot install it for Python 3.4.3 (unless you want to do the work on porting it yourself, which they've been stuck on for a few years at this point…).

There are a number of other MySQL libraries for Python, which are Python 3-compatible. And some of them come with wheels (or come with binary installers, or are pure-Python via `ctypes`, or just by natively talking the protocol). Choose one of those instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i downgraded to Python 2.7, I am now able to install MySQL-python.